# HVAC - bathroom vent in attic space

Tags: hvac, attic, exhaust-fan

Looks like my crappy builder did not do a very good job with the vent in my attic space as it already detached from the exterior wall. Any advice as to what products I can buy and affix back onto the wall such that this doesn’t happen again? [image: attic vent]

Answer (score 4):

An actual wall vent duct termination, rather than gluing a flex duct to a round vent not designed for a duct, from what can be seen here.

That will have a solid metal collar inside the house to attach the duct to.